# What is the fastest way to multiply a number by 2?

Tags: performance, numbers, multiplication

I am aware that there are multiple ways of multiplying numbers by 2:

```
v << 1
v * 2
v >> -1
v + v
v - -v
```

Which is fastest?
I am using Assembly on an intel x86 processor.

Comment: The fastest on which processor? What programming language? Which compiler version? There are way too much factors that have an impact. Many compilers will optimize all the below command to one command...

Comment: What's wrong with `*`?

Comment: I'm using Intel 4 processor 2.0 ghz in assembly on windows.

Comment: Implementation dependant, compiler should figure it out for you... Some hardware can't multiply in one click cycle etc...

Comment: That isn't assembly...

Comment: I put it in C so it was easier to understand as I understand not everyone knows assembly.

Answer (score 1):

There's obviously not one answer here.  The answer will depend on the specific processor in use, at least.

Most of the time, your compiler will know, so most of the time, you can just write `* 2` in your code, maximizing clarity to your readers *and* efficiency.

If you really care, you'll have to perform careful measurements yourself.

(Also, multiplying by two is so basic that there might not even *be* a measurable difference between `v * 2`, `v + v`, and `v << 1`.)